# How to run shutil.copy2() function with sudo permission within a python3.6 script run with normal user permission?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

Below is what I would like to do. This script is executed with normal user permission but it has to copy a file to a location owned by the root user. How do I use `shutil.copy2()` to perform the copy? An alternative is to use the `subprocess.run()` to run a bash cp command. But without going that route, I would like to know the pythonic way of dealing with such a scenario. Or is the `subprocess.run()` function the only way to copy a file to a root user location?

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import run
import sys 

ext_schema_name = f'org.gnome.shell.extensions.arc-menu.gschema.xml'
ext_schema_path = Path( f'/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/arc-menu@linxgem33.com/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.arc-menu.gschema.xml' )

glib_schemas = Path( '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/' )
ext_glib_schema_path = glib_schemas / ext_schema_name

#This cmd should not work due to invalid permission. 
#What is the pythonic way to do this?
shutil.copy2( ext_schema_path, ext_glib_schema_path )

#The subprocess alternative that should work
run( f'pkexec cp  {ext_schema_path} {ext_glib_schema_path}', shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout )
```